# Extreme Redshift Detection

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy, radio-frequency

There is a [new paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07769) in arXiv postulating that black holes might actually let some let some light out. This of course is very theoretical, but it postulates that the light would be redshifted to 640 Astronomical Units. How would we be able to detect this?
Here is a snippet by Popular Mechanics on it
https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/deep-space/amp35875454/what-are-black-holes-new-theory/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the paper mentioned isn't dealing with classical black holes, they're working with an alternative hypothesis called a 'dark star'. Unlike a black hole, it has no horizon. Similarly, this isn't a new area of study (e.g. see https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0346 for a review).

In this specific case, the horizon is replaced with a strong gravitational well. Hence emitted photons are extremely redshifted, the value they quote is $z \approx 10^{49}$ (meaning the photons have a wavelength of $\lambda \approx 10^{14}$m). This is utterly out of the realms of ever being detected - this is also stated in the article you linked. For reference, the wavelengths of CMB photons today are of the order mm-cm, so their energies are orders of magnitude larger than those emitted here.